# How to create a wave-net-like CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I would like to create a CNN in a similar way to WaveNet architecture.

i.e. on the first layer it takes convolves 3x3 areas.
In the next layer it also convolves 9 pixels but spaced out like this:

```
x x x
.....
x.x.x
.....
x.x.x
```

And so on with the next layer spacing them out even more. Thereby not needing the max-pooling layers.

The idea is that it has a similar structure to Wavenet but in 2D and you would end up with the same number of neurons in each layer.

Then the output should be a map of the image with different colours for each object in the image such as a cat, a dog or a tree.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in Tensorflow. Or has this already been implemented perhaps?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/atrous_conv2d is what you're looking for

Comment: Looks like it. Has there been much work done with this? And more importantly does it work?

Comment: Yes, it is frequently used for semantic segmentation, where the current state-of-the-art method has a big CNN with atrous convs. see: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05587

Comment: Ah I see WaveNet was inspired by the CNN model rather than the other way round.